# Sprite Kit collision detection and physics

Tags: collision-detection, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Hi all I am making a game where the enemy should not be able to go through walls and items in the game like for example if there is a wall, the enemy's character should not be able to go through it. however, I can't get the physics to work exactly right. I want the enemy be stopped if it tries to run into another sprite like a wall.

Thanks guys.

```
- (void) Enemy {
_Enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
_Enemy.position = CGPointMake(520, _Enemy.size.height/1.50);
[self addChild:_Enemy];
```

}

```
- (void) EnemyHomeWalls {
Wall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Thewall@2x"];
wall.name = @"Thewall";
wall.position = CGPointMake(500, 150);
Wall.xScale = 0.12;
Wall.yScale = 0.12;
Wall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
[self addChild:Wall];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need the enemy node to have a physicsBody as well:

```
_Enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_Enemy.size];
```

To prevent the node from being affected by gravity, you can set

```
_Enemy.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

Or, in the initWithSize method,

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
```

You need to study the [SKPhysicsBody class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I have tried that but what would happen is that all sudden the enemy's character would have some sort of gravity and it falls down to the bottom edge and stops there.

Comment: Almost but not quite. because what happens now is that if the enemy runs into the wall, it gets stuck there and won't move away. how can I solve that? thanks bud by the way.

Comment: How are you controlling the movement of the enemy sprite?

Comment: its random. computer does that based on random x and y positions.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Please add the code for that. I am sure you are using SKActions which do not work well if you want your nodes to be simulated correctly using physics.